# PHPのリクエストURLのファイルの表示方法について

Tags: php, apache

ずばりPHPのリクエストURLのファイルの表示方法を知りたいです。(インターネットで調べても全く出てきませんでした(調べ方が悪いだけかもしれませんが))

例えば、 localhost:3000/index.htmlにアクセスしたらindex.htmlを表示する、といった感じのことをしたいです。
回答お願いいたします。

Comment: 単純なHTMLのページを表示するだけなら user35025 さんの回答で解決されているかもしれませんが、タイトルにあるPHPを表示(=動作)させる場合にはApacheに追加の設定が必要な場合があります。/ 必要に応じてより適切なタイトルや質問文に見直してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

apacheのルートフォルダにある`htdocs`に突っ込むだけです
https://www.adminweb.jp/apache/docroot/index1.html

Comment: apacheをインストールしたら正常に動作しました！